# Loop through XPath element positions in Python using Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How can I loop through element positions in Python using Selenium?

I've tried this and it's not working:

```
for i in range(2,21):
    un = browser.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='cname'])[i]").text
    print(un)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to format your string to put inside `i` value:

```
for i in range(2,21):
    un = browser.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='cname'])[{0}]".format(i)).text
    print(un)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your code block an alternative would be to to use `find_elements_by_xpath` along with the index `[i]` as follows :

```
for i in range(2,21):
    un = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='cname']")[i].text
    print(un)
```